# Is Batman: Mask of the Phantasm the same universe as Batman the Animated Series?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe, mask-of-the-phantasm

Are the events from the movie Batman: Mask of the Phantasm considered to be taking place in the universe depicted in Batman: the Animated Series or the two things just have the same "look and feel"? (I mean, is a film merely based on the show but that does not expand nor alter the universe of the show).

I will accept any references to the Phantasm, Andrea, or any other characters or events first seen on the movie and then seen in the Animated Series as proof of it. Any other explanation of why it is so (or why not) is of course welcome. I also understand that there may be "lack of evidence", but I hope that somebody can point to something in any of the series' 85 episodes that will proof one thing or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some more research I'm positive that the answer is **yes, they can be considered part of the same universe**.

In spite of the intentions on which the movie was created (as an independent story or not), the episode *Batman: The Animated Series, Beware The Creeper*, features a possible origin for the Joker, and in the episode's documentary (hosted by Jack Ryder) there is a picture that is brought from Mask of the Phantasm.

I think that this can be considered more that just homage, and it uses the **same characters and in the same context** (if not the Joker, at least Beaumont and his associates), and since these characters were created for Mask of the Phantasm it can't be considered a reuse of some old character in a different context/background/Elseworld. Is a set of characters created for the movie that appear within the exact same context in the animated sereis. So both stories get to be connected and coherent.

Comment: Your video link is dead.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, this is confirmed in an oblique way later on in the *Justice League Unlimited* episode *Epilogue*, which ties together *Batman: The Animated Series*, *Batman: Mask of the Phantasm*, *Batman Beyond*, and *Justice League/JLU*.

As part of the reveal of Terry's (a *Batman Beyond* character) secret origin, Amanda Waller (a *Justice League* character) hires an assassin (The Phantasm) to murder Terry's parents, thus ensuring he would become a new Batman.  This shows that the character existed after the events of *Mask of the Phantasm*, and is tied into the later entries in the DCAU.

*Batman Beyond* is explicitly linked to *Batman: The Animated Series* in multiple ways.  The big one is the film *Batman Beyond: Return of the Joker*, which provides conclusions to the stories of several members of the characters from *Batman: The Animated Series*.

Therefore, *Batman: The Animated Series* is linked to *Batman Beyond*, which in turn is linked to *Justice League* and finally *Batman: Mask of the Phantasm*.

Comment: Too oblique? That would tie Mask of the Phantasm and Batman Beyond, provided that The Phantasm is the same character altogether, and not different versions of the same character, like using the Joker (or any other character) in two different series and giving him a different origin in each. It could even be a "cameo" or homage appearance, not necessarily The Phantasm of that other "Timeline"/universe. If you bring up Batman Beyond you would need to "close the loop", because maybe is widely know (probably requires its own question) but, is Batman Beyond the same universe as Batman TAS?

Comment: @Deion Batman: TAS, Batman Beyond, Justice League, and Justice League Unlimited (amongst other shows) are all one universe.  I'm referring to a JLU episode here, not Batman Beyond.

Comment: yes, it's called the DC Animated Universe, also colloquially known as the Timmverse after Bruce Timm. It includes Static Shock and the Zeta Project as well.

Epilogue is my favourite episode in all of television.

Comment: “Therefore, Batman: The Animated Series is linked to Batman Beyond, which in turn is linked to Justice League and finally Batman: Mask of the Phantasm.” — The real question is did Tommy Westphall appear in any of them?

Comment: What is this - Six Degrees of Batman???

Comment: @user1027- Hold up, from what I remember of Batman Beyond Terry's mother was  still alive, and his dad was killed on the orders of Drek Powers (the sob who took over running Wanyecorp).

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the production notes from wikipedia seems to indicate that, while it was related to TAS, it was not canon.

> Although the Joker does play a pivotal role in the film, it was Burnett's intention to tell a story far removed from the television show's regular rogues gallery.

[Batman: Mask of the Phantasm Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Mask_of_the_Phantasm)

Though this could be interpeted to mean it is removed from the usual pace of the TV show, I take it to mean that the movie itself is removed from the constraints of said show.

Comment: Great answer too, but is still unclear. And even if they had intentionally written the story for the movie to be non-canon, they could have changed their minds later, and add a reference to the Phantasm (like bat cave memorabilia) or included references that could be consistent with the background stories for Bruce or the Joker in any episodes of TAS.